# Linux find command is not giving proper result while using inside a fuction

Tags: linux

```
_zip_cmd() {
    find . -maxdepth 1 ! -path . -type f ${pattern} -mtime +${days} -exec gzip {} \;
}
```

I am using the above function in a shell script. The variable `${pattern}` and `${days}` would be in a properties file or it can used as script argument while executing.

${pattern} would be:   ! -name "*data*" or similar to this and may be provided multiple times.

like ! -name "*data*" ! -name "*script*"  -name "*error*" .......

The script is taking the argument(s) given but it is zipping all the file including pattern "*data*" n "*script*" matched file.

Even I have given (\) before * , but no luck.
Can you provide me a solution to use ?

Comment: Does this fail the same way from the command line?  Also, when run from the command line, without "-exec gzip {}", what does the output look like?

Comment: Perhaps better place parameters within quotes. If the variable contains spaces, it will be *reinterpreted* as two separate parameters.

Comment: In command prompt It is working fine. But inside the script it is not giving the expected result.